# Can we make a triangular background using xml in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, drawable

I was wondering if we could make a triangular drawable using xml in android studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in API 21 you can use `Vector drawable`. so in the `drawable` folder create `triangle.xml` file.

like this way.

**triangle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:viewportHeight="100"
    android:viewportWidth="100" >
    <group
        android:name="triableGroup">
        <path
            android:name="triangle"
            android:fillColor="#FF0000"
            android:pathData="m 50,0 l 50,100 -100,0 z" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

and apply your `View` background.